# How to update same type multiple objects with factory_formset django?

Tags: python, django

I want to update multiple objects (formset). I have a model and I can to create  multiple objects with this:

```
class FormSeguridadView(CreateView):
    v = 0
    insp = 0
    form_class = RespFormSeguridad
    RespFormset = formset_factory(RespFormSeguridad, extra=0)
    template_name = 'formularios/formSeguridad.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        v = self.v
        insp = self.insp
        context = super(FormSeguridadView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['pregDocuObra'] = PRG.objects.filter(PRG_TIP=1)
        context['seguridad_form'] = self.RespFormset(initial=[
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 11},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 12},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 13},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 14},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 19},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 20},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 21},
            {'RESP_INSP': insp, 'RESP_FORM': v, 'RESP_PRG': 22},
        ])

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resp_formset = self.RespFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

        if resp_formset.is_valid():
            for respuestas in resp_formset:
                respuestas.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            print(resp_formset.errors)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

And this is my part from my form.py:

```
class RespFormSeguridad(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RESP
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       super(RespFormSeguridad, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['RESP_FORM'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
       self.fields['RESP_PRG'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
       self.fields['RESP_INSP'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
       self.fields['RESP_RESUL'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

But i tried to update with this code:

```
class FormSeguridadUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = RespFormSeguridad
    template_name = 'formularios/formSeguridadUpdate.html'
    queryset = RESP.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        id_ = self.kwargs['pk']
        return get_list_or_404(RESP, RESP_INSP=2)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

But it doesn't work. It Throws an error:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  190.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
  66.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
  33.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\app\forms.py" in __init__
  37.        super(RespFormSeguridad, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __init__
  292.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Proyectos\inspecciones-moneleg\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in model_to_dict
  82.     opts = instance._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /inspections/1/updateFormSeguridad/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I dont know how to resolve this. Maybe it is not the solution for edit multiple objects. If someone knows to resolve this, please comment here.

Comment: Can you add the full error stacktrace? We cannot guess where the error orginates.

Comment: can you add the code for the `__init__()` method of `RespFormSeguridad` ? That seems to be the only call in the error stacktrace that is custom code.

Comment: Check it, i add it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django 1.10 / AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '\_meta'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811354/django-1-10-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-meta)

Comment: Not the same. I want to update multiple forms. If i use get_object_or_404 is for one instance not 8 in my case. I have a model where i many answers. Model of Answer is "RESP". If i have 8 question i want save 8 answers. So i had to use factory_formset to create. Now i want to update the 8 answers. I hope that you understand me. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

The error is being raised because you return a list from the method `get_object()`, but that method should return a model instance (an instance of a subclass of `models.Model`).

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    ...
    return get_list_or_404(RESP, RESP_INSP=2)   # this causes the ERROR
```

The [linked related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811354/django-1-10-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-meta) mentioned in a comment to the question points this out as well.

I read your comment that you want to update many instances and not just one, but I don't think overriding `get_object()` is the right way to do it.
That being said, I don't know how to solve your issue, I just added this answer to explain where the error is comming from.